How to build a bar plot for funnel analysis when the raw data is boolean columns per person per month
I have data about people in different months. For each person, there's a row per month, for whether they were:

drinking enough water in the month (TRUE/FALSE)
having any headaches in the month (TRUE/FALSE)
died in the month (TRUE/FALSE)

The data
# | person_id | month      | drank_below_2_cups_of_water | had_headache | died  |
# |-----------|------------|-----------------------------|--------------|-------|
# | 1         | 2024-02-01 | TRUE                        | TRUE         | FALSE |
# | 1         | 2024-03-01 | TRUE                        | FALSE        | TRUE  |
# | 2         | 2024-02-01 | FALSE                       | TRUE         | FALSE |
# | 2         | 2024-03-01 | TRUE                        | FALSE        | FALSE |
# | 3         | 2024-02-01 | FALSE                       | FALSE        | FALSE |
# | 3         | 2024-03-01 | TRUE                        | TRUE         | TRUE  |
# | 4         | 2024-02-01 | TRUE                        | FALSE        | FALSE |
# | 4         | 2024-03-01 | FALSE                       | TRUE         | TRUE  |
# | 5         | 2024-02-01 | FALSE                       | FALSE        | FALSE |
# | 5         | 2024-03-01 | TRUE                        | TRUE         | FALSE |
# | 6         | 2024-02-01 | FALSE                       | FALSE        | FALSE |
# | 6         | 2024-03-01 | TRUE                        | TRUE         | TRUE  |

What I'm trying to accomplish
Visualize a funnel analysis using a bar chart. Meaning:

How many people had TRUE in drank_below_2_cups_of_water (n = 7, see green cells)  ;
Out of them, how many people had TRUE in had_headache (n = 4, see purple cells) ;
Out of them, how many people had TRUE in died (n = 2, see orange cells)


Desired output
Two separate bar plots that visualize the counts above, yet in a different way of calculating the proportions between bars.
1 – Relative to first bar

2 – Relative to previous bar

It's critical that in either plot, I want to label both counts and proportions on bars top.
My current attempt to solve the problem
I tried creating separate calculated fields.
// A
sum(if [Drank Below 2 Cups Of Water] then 1 else 0 end)

// B
sum(if [Had Headache] AND [Drank Below 2 Cups Of Water] then 1 else 0 end)

// C
sum(if [Died] and [Had Headache] and [Drank Below 2 Cups Of Water] then 1 else 0 end)

// A (rel to A)
[A] / [A]

// B (rel to A)
[B] / [A]

// C (rel to A)
[C] / [A]

Then, bringing them over to the canvas as separate fields we get almost what I need. I just want to know how to add the counts too, not just the proportions (see below in red – that's what I'm still missing).


Any idea how to achieve that? I'm open to any other suggestions, including structuring the data differently. I'm new to Tableau so looking for a best practice solution, as much as there is one.

FYI, the INT() function converts True to 1 and False to 0. So you can write a more concise calculated field to count records that satisfy a condition, such as SUM(INT([Had Headache])) And [Whatever]). I think it is a little easier to read once you get used to it, by removing the clutter. You can also leave off the SUM() in the calculation since that will be the default aggregation when you use the field as a measure

Create a calculated field and call it [People Count]:
 COUNT([Person Id]) //or COUNTD if you want distinct counts, although odd if someone dies twice...

Drag [People Count] to the Label box in the Marks Pane
Format as needed.
